# For any irrational number $r$, $r^2$ is irrational

Tags: discrete-mathematics, irrational-numbers

Is the following statement true of false?

> For any irrational number $r$, $r^2$ is irrational.

How can I prove this? I'm confused. Can I use $r=\frac{a}{b}$?

Comment: What about $\sqrt{2}$?

Answer (score 5):

It's false; $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational and $\sqrt{2}^2=2$ is not.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: It may be easier to consider the [**contrapositive**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition).

The statement you're looking at is true if and only if the following statement is true: $$\mbox{Every rational number has a rational square root.}$$

(i) Do you see why these two statements are equivalent?

(ii) Can you think of a rational number with an **ir**rational square root?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why the downvote?